# Add character at every vowel

Tags: c++, string

I had a similiar question earlier and managed to solve it. Now I'm trying to do it backwards, this is my code at the moment.

Basically I want the end result to "p5A5SSW5o5R5o5d", but when I run this it just find the first "o" which is in the first part of passworod, I need it to skip the the vowel it have already added a 5 before and after to.

I want every vowel (only included AOao in the current string as thats all the vowels appearing in my string), to have a 5 as prefix and suffix. It gets stuck at the first o and doesnt proceed to the next o. I have created a nested for loop which means it takes the first character in the encrypt-string, proceeds to the next for-loop and loops through every single vowel Ive included in the vowel string until it finds a match. Otherwise it restarts at the first for-loop but incremented by one. First go it should search the letter "p", second run it should search the letter "A" and so on.

Result: p**5**A**5**SSW**55**o**55**rod

Expected Result: p**5**A**5**SSW**5**o**5**R**5**o**5**d

In the end I will also want to rotate all the characters, but thats for another task, I think I can just use either if-statement or a switch to do that. If it ends up on a 5, do nothing, otherwise rotate.

I hope I made myself clear and provided you with all the relevant information, otherwise just holler in the comments.

Thanks in advance.

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

const string vowel = "AOao";
string encrypt, decrypt;
encrypt = "pASSWoRod";
decrypt = encrypt;


 for (int i=0; i<encrypt.length(); i++){
        for (int j=0; j<vowel.length(); j++){
            if (encrypt[i] == vowel[j]){

                    decrypt.insert(decrypt.find(vowel[j]), 1, '5');
                    decrypt.insert(decrypt.find(vowel[j]) + 1, +1, '5');

            }
        }
    }

return decrypt;
}
```

Comment: Build the new string from scratch instead of trying to manipulate the existing string.  Every call to `insert` invokes a copy operation on your string, thus making this approach (more than likely) slower than just building a new string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find` with one argument starts from the beginning. You would need the other [find](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/string-find-in-cpp/).

However maintaing an index in decrypt, one no longer would need a find.

```
int encryptI = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < decrypt.length(); i++, encyptI++){
    for (int j=0; j<vowel.length(); j++){
        if (decrypt[i] == vowel[j]){
                //encryptI = encrypt.find(vowel[j], encryptI);
                encrypt.insert(encryptI, 1, '5');
                encrypt.insert(encryptI + 1, +1, '5');
                encryptI += 2;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

The code could be nicer.

```
string encrypt;
for (int i = 0; i < decrypt.length(); i++, decyptI++){
    char ch = decrypt[i];
    if (vowel.find(ch) != string::npos) {
        encrypt.append('5');
        encrypt.append(ch);
        encrypt.append('5');
    } else {
        encrypt.append(ch);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Mori I have switch encrypt and decrypt, as the original loop was over encrypt

Answer (score 3):

`find`, when not proved a starting point, always finds the first instance.

Searching and keeping track of the string length and where you've already inserted characters is much harder than it seems at first glance (as you've noticed).

Build the result from scratch instead of inserting characters into an initial string.

Also, implement this function (actual implementation left as an exercise):

```
bool is_vowel(char c);
```

and then

```
std::string encrypt = "pASSWoRod";
std::string decrypt;
for (auto c: encrypt)
{
    if (is_vowel(c))
    {
        decrypt += '5';
        decrypt += c;
        decrypt += '5';
    }
    else
    {
        decrypt += c;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I'm getting this error:
undefined reference to `is_vowel(char)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: @Trollblod Because you didn't implement it.

Comment: Oh right, won't it be able to have this working within a function? This is already my 3rd function (besides main). And the "pASSWoRod" is actually passed to this function as a return value from the one above. I wrote it as a separate string in here to make it easier to read.

Otherwise it's encrypt = password; (taken from the function previously).

Comment: @Trollblod Having several functions is rarely a problem, and three isn't exactly a lot. It's a far more common problem to have too few.

Answer (score 0):

Your `find` is stopping at the first instance of the vowel, 'o'. You should include a starting position for your find so you ignore the part of the decrypt string you've already analyzed.

Comment: I tried doing this by adding " decrypt.insert(decrypt[i].find(vowel[j]), 1, '5');" But that is not acceptable with the find syntax.

Comment: find(vowel[j], start_pos) is the syntax you need. start_pos should be where you placed the last 5, which you would need to keep track of somewhere. But you can also do it more elegantly as @molbdnilo points out.